# grayscale css is not working on android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am working on phonegap application here I am trying to grayscale of my all page of the application so I try to apply this css on the body. It's not working for android, but it's working fine for iOS after that I also tried to apply on one element but again it's not working. Please can you help me to get out of this problem

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Comment: Android < 4.4 and css filters is problematic, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     filter: grayscale(100%); /* Current draft standard */
```

Filters for other browser are:

```
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* New WebKit */    
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Not yet supported in Gecko, Opera or IE */ 
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); 
    filter: gray; /* IE */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Old WebKit */
```

Comment: hi abhishek it's not working for android can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

img{

filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);

}